# How to only allow one radio button to be checked and then be able to process it in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a simple list of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="normal" name="casing" value="Normal">
<label for="male">Normal</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="upper" name="casing" value="Uppercase">
<label for="female">Uppercase</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="lower" name="casing" value="Lowercase">
<label for="other">Lowercase</label>
```

I understand then when wanting to only allow one item to be selected, I have to give them the same name, as I did. But when wanting to then process the information in PHP, I cannot access it since they have the same name.
The other way would be to give them different names

```
<input type="radio" id="casing" name="normal" value="Normal">
<label for="male">Normal</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="casing" name="upper" value="Uppercase">
<label for="female">Uppercase</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="casing" name="lower" value="Lowercase">
<label for="other">Lowercase</label>
```

This allows me to process the data in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["upper"])){
  $wort = strtoupper($_POST["wort"]);
  echo "<b>Das Wort:</b> $wort <br>";
  echo "<b> Anzahl der Zeichen: </b> " . strlen($wort) . "<br>";
  if(isset($_POST["reverse"])){
  echo "<b> Reverse-Ausgabe: </b> " . reverse($wort) . "<br>";
}
```

How do I only allow one button to be selected while being able to process it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="normal" name="casing" value="Normal">
<label for="male">Normal</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="upper" name="casing" value="Uppercase">
<label for="female">Uppercase</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="lower" name="casing" value="Lowercase">
<label for="other">Lowercase</label>
```

The value of the selected radio button will be returned to the PHP in

```
$_POST["casing"]
```

because the `name=` attribute was `name="casing"`

It's value will be one of `Normal`, `Uppercase` or `Lowercase`

So check using

```
if ( isset($_POST['casing'] && $_POST['casing'] == 'Normal') {
```

Remember the `name` attribute controls that name of the name=value pair placed in the $_POST assoc array name the `id` is only used in the browser, by javacript usually

Comment: So to decide which part of the code to run do I do if ($_POST["casing"] == "upper"){  } for example?

Comment: Yes thats would be it